# How to get the geolocation of a google maps app shared dropped pin?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm writing my own android app and I want to offer the user the possibility to share a location (address/geolocation) from the Google Maps app.

I managed to register my app as an intent listener and receive the shared string. But this string only contains a rather vague description of the address and a shortened google link, like this:

```
1029 E 29th St

https://goo.gl/maps/G9UbkTH3R9B2
```

When I follow that link (on the device or on my computer), google maps is opened and the correct location is shown. So that is working just fine.

What I want is to get the address of that location, preferably in the shape of an `Address` object. I just couldn't find any api description to do so. **How do I get the address of the shared location?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a little hacky, but it serves the purpose (mostly).

You can find a good part of the address in query of the resolved url. Try the following:

```
String url = ... // the URL from your shared string
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

while (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK &&
        responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP ||
        responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM ||
        responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
    url = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

    if (url.contains("q=")) {
        break;
    }

    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
    responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
}
```

`url` now contains the query. Extract that:

```
for (String t : queryUrl.substring(queryUrl.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&")) {
    if (t.startsWith("q=")) {
        url = URLDecoder.decode(t.substring(2));
    }
}
```

Now, `url` contains the decoded address description that is used in the google search query. You can use that String to get an `address` object from the `Geocoder` class (requires a context):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> fromLocationName = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
```

There you have your address(es). The second parameter in the `getFromLocationName()` method call denotes the maximum number of results expected. If you want to prompt the user to choose an explicit result object, use a higher number here.

**Open Issues**

Now to the downside of it. Sometimes, the query is not an address description but a pair of coordinates (lat/long). In this case, the address object received from the geocoder does not necesserily return the same coordinates as were given in the query. It's your decission how to deal with this.

In some cases I found out that there is no query url. Instead, there is a `cid` value in the url. I couldn't yet figure out what to do with that. Unfortunately, neither does the `Geocoder`. But maybe someone else knows what to do with that.